# How were the Beta badges awarded?

Tags: discussion, beta, badges

How did one get the Beta badge?
I was a member from before and through the Private Beta and didn't get it, so just curious what the requirements were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post from meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/105#105) Beta badges are for those who achieved at least three badges of any kind during private beta.

Comment: Dig it.  Only had two.  And you wouldnt know that from the badge description, but hey, its just a few pixels after all.  :)